# How to avoid views to get on top of each other during the animation?

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote a method for views which moves views in random directions. But I would like to improve it to avoid views to get on top of each other during that movement. Is there a way to improve my code:

```
@objc func bottomAnimationLoop(_ animationID: String?, finished: NSNumber?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(20)

    [v5, v6, v7, v8, v9].forEach { (vi) in
        let topRandomY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2) + 1) + UInt32(UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2)
        let x = CGFloat(arc4random() % UInt32(view.bounds.size.width))
        let y = CGFloat(topRandomY % UInt32(view.bounds.size.height))

        let squarePostion = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
        vi.center = squarePostion
    }

    UIView.setAnimationDelegate(self)
    UIView.setAnimationDidStop(#selector(bottomAnimationLoop(_:finished:context:)))

    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

Comment: Well, this is not relevant to what you asked, but one way to improve your code is to stop using the `begin` `set` `commit` syntax. It is deprecated, and has been outmoded for many years. There is absolutely no reason to use it here.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by *"avoid views to get on top of each other"* ... Do you want to generate "paths" that don't intersect? Do you want a view to "pause and let the other guy go first"? Do you want the views to stop if they collide? If you take the time to think through what you *want* to happen, that often gives you your answer.